# How to perform contain operation between a numpy array and a vector row-wise?

Tags: python, numpy

Now I have a numpy array,

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [2 5]]
```

and a vector.

```
[2,
 5,
 2]
```

I want to perform a contain operation between the array and the vector row wise. In other words, I want to check whether the first row `[1, 2]`contain `2`, whether the second row `[3, 4]` contain `5`. The expected output would look like:

```
[True, False, True]
```

How could I implement this function? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can broadcast the vector into a column, equate it to all the elements in the rows of the matrix, and see if [`any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) element is `True` in each row:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
    [[1, 2],
     [3, 4],
     [2, 5]])
v = np.array([2, 5, 2]).reshape(-1, 1)

np.any(a == v, axis=1)
```

https://ideone.com/YmWtlv

[`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) turns your 1D (row) vector into a column vector. This is necessary because normally [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) lines up the shapes along the right, so you need an explicit trailing dimension of 1. Another way to accomplish the same thing is to use [`newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) (a.k.a. `None`):

```
v = np.array([2, 5, 2])[..., np.newaxis]
```

*Note*

My original answer suggested [`reduce`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) using [`logical_or`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html), which is just a more complicated way of saying `any`:

```
np.logical_or.reduce(a == v, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 6):

using a list comprehension and zip

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4],[2, 5]])
a = np.array([2,5,2])

[y in x for x, y in zip(arr, a)]
# outputs: [True, False, True]
```

Using np.any with `axis=1`:

```
np.any(arr == a[:, None], axis=1)
# outputs: array([ True, False,  True])
```

Comment: The any solution is the best one here. Not sure what the point of first part is though.

Comment: the list comprehension was just the first that came to my mind.

Answer (score 6):

This one-liner should do it. It works for any number of columns, too.

```
# Set up
import numpy as np
array = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4],[2, 5]])
vector = np.array([2,5,2])

# Solution
result = np.logical_or.reduce(array == vector[:,None], 1)
```

Output:

```
[ True, False,  True]
```

This compares all of the elements against the *column* vector `vector` and then reduces over rows.

Comment: yes, numpy is all about speed. But could you explain when I can use `reduce` after `ufunc` generally? Thanks.

Comment: The only thing you're missing is broadcasting. There is no need to create a whole extra matrix of ones and multiplying by it.

Answer (score 3):

We can also make use of broadcasting and the dot product.

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [2, 5]])
b = np.array([2, 5, 2])
```

Solution

```
(a == b[:,None]) @ np.array([1, 1]).astype(bool)
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist thank you. Yours is very clever as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the first column and second column of the 2D array with the vector and perform a `logical or` operation on the results obtained.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4],[2, 5]])
b = [2,5,2]
np.logical_or(a[:,0] == b , a[:,1] == b)
```

**Output:**

```
array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: @QYang - the solution I gave in my answer is about 3x faster than this one because it doesn't require unpacking the columns of `a`.

Comment: This is not a very general solution.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I agree. It looks like other answers, yours including, have a better solution. Isn't a downvote too harsh?

Comment: Fair enough. Your solution is functional after all I suppose.